# Displaying React native listview items in equal chunks

Tags: css, reactjs, listview, react-native

I'm working on a eCommerce React Native project. I have a cart component which contains a Listview of all current items within the Cart. The main issue is the styling. I display each product according to quantiy - product name - price and delete button.

So something like this

[image]

As you can see the price text is not aligned equally and varies depending on product name. How can I edit the style so all text and buttons within the list view are equal length?

Answer (score 0):

Each Text field can be assigned a flex value like this:

```
        <Text style={{flex: 0.1}}>{product.quantity}x</Text>
        <Text style={{padding: 10, flex:0.5}}>{product.name.toString()}</Text>
        <Text style={{flex: 0.2}}>£{(product.quantity * product.price).toFixed(2)}</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity style={{flex: 0.2}} onPress={() => { this.removeItem(product) }}>
```

The total of the 0.* should equal to 1.